# Cordova, Android, deprecated Gradle features

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, gradle-plugin, cordova-android

I'm building an application with Cordova. I added the android and ios platforms, I installed all the packages that are required by the requirements. When I build the app with cordova build, there is a problem with android, **especially gradle version**

Here the error

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
```

I also installed Gradle 7 to try to solve it, through brew I made a link of Gradle8 and the link of Gradle7, but launching

```
cordova build
```

I get the exact same error

**What can be done to fix it?**

Comment: What's your cordova version ?

Answer (score 0):

A Java version between 8 and 19 is required to execute Gradle. Java 20 and later versions are not yet supported.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).